# как выравнять блоки по горизонтали?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

html:

```
                out+='<div class="quant">';
                    out+='<div class="val-min"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></div>';
                    out+='<div class="val">2</div>';
                    out+='<div class="val-plus"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></div>';
                out+='</div>';
```

css:

```
  .val-min,.val-plus, .val{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;

    width: 40px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 18px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
    line-height: 24px;
}
.val-min:hover,.val-plus:hover{
   background: #b2b2b2;
}
.fa-minus, .fa-plus{
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #2E2E2E ;
}
```

Comment: vertical-align: top

Comment: @humster_spb,спасибо!